# Spring boot thymeleaf cannot return HTML page even after many different solutions on Stack Overflow and Google Search

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Spring returns

> Circular view path [code]: would dispatch back to the current handler
> URL [/code] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be
> the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name
> generation.)

when trying to access localhost:port/code

and

[IntelliJ IDEA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA) also gives

> Cannot resolve MVC view 'code'

when I hover on "code".

Controller class:

```
package platform;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class controller {

    @GetMapping("/code")
    public String returnCode(){
        return "code";
    }
}
```

File *code.html* is located at *resources/templates/code.html*;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title>Code</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <pre id="code_snippet">
        code.com
    </pre>
</body>
</html>
```

Main method:

```
package platform;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CodeSharingPlatform {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CodeSharingPlatform.class, args);
    }
}
```

File *build.gradle*:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.3.3.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

sourceCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs = ["src/resources"]

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
}
```

I even followed the tutorial *[Serving Web Content with Spring MVC](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/), but their method doesn't work for some reason...

Comment: Is there a reason why you set `sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs` to `src/resources` instead of using the default (`src/main/resources`)? And what's the full path of your html file? I suspect is Spring Boot couldn't find the template file, so it send the request back to the controller `/code`.

Comment: @Dickson thats not the case apparently, the project specifies the resources file to be under src; the path is .\task\src\resources\templates\code.html

Comment: @GovindaSakhare that's not the case, I tried that method already. Instead I think its missing some libraries or something

Comment: I tested with the exact same configuration, it works for me. Can you show a screenshot of your project structure of all your files?

Comment: @Dickson I solved it due to some weird IDE error

Answer (score 0):

I was missing some libraries from thymeleaf. All I had to do was to restart my IDE lol or resync Gradle.